# Send user control as reference?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I have a main form and a couple of user control. Right now i am accessing one of the user controls through the other using the active form and then referencing the user control.
But this makes it difficult if the focus is on some other window.
Is there a way to get the instance of the user control without instantiating a new instance of the user control or using the active form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may access the form which is hosting your user control, via [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property and later you can get list of your user controls from the form like:

```
if ((Application.OpenForms["yourForm"] as Form1) != null)
{
    var YourUserControlList = 
                      (Application.OpenForms["yourForm"] as Form1)
                                    .Controls.OfType<YourUserControl>()
                                    .ToList();
}
```

where `yourForm` is the ID of your Form, and `YourUserControl` is the class name of your user control

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need to do is to actually make the event on one form public and add a handler to the other so it can be triggered when the first form fires its event. This way there is a formal way for one to reference or associate-with the other.